# How to view only doc text with pydoc

Tags: python, perl, pydoc, perldoc

Being a perl developer I am aware of the **perldoc** utility. I am new to python  and I was looking for same and found **pydoc**. 
But the problem with pydoc is it is **also executing my script** while I want to see only doc written inside triple quotes.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way is to work in Python (instead of the command line). Let's take the module `sys` as an example. First import your module and then use `help()`, like this:

```
import sys
help(sys)
```

If you want to see the docstrings:

```
print(sys.__doc__)
```

For modules you develop yourself, you can build in a guard so that the module is not executed, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html):

> Note: In order to find objects and their documentation, pydoc imports the module(s) to be documented. Therefore, any code on module level will be executed on that occasion. Use an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to only execute code when a file is invoked as a script and not just imported.

Comment: Scenario is my script expects some command line arguments. When I use either the way you suggested or pydoc, it's asking for those arguments. Ideally, it should only be displaying doc strings.

Comment: It worked @Honie. Though I had to intend the entire code in this IF block. Thanks.